# Помогите с регуляркой в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите написать правильное регулярное выражение в htaccess.

У меня прописано такое правило

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ inex.php?val=$1&val1=$2&val2=$3
```

Оно работает нормально, но мне нужно чтобы когда в строке, а именно в val2, было слово "page" срабатывало не это правило, а следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/page-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?val=$1&val1=$2&page=$3
```

Пробовал вот так прописать первое правило

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(^[?!.*page]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ inex.php?val=$1&val1=$2&val2=$3
```

но не получатся, исключает только символы p,a,g,e, а мне нужно, чтобы исключало слово page. Подскажите возможно ли так сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Второе правило (оно у вас более узкое по охвату) поставьте первым в очереди.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для правил в `mod_rewrite` есть "модификатор" `[L]`, который говорит, что при срабатывании этого правила другие просматривать не надо.

В вашем случае, правила надо поменять местами. То, которое, "ловит" `page` надо поставить первым и добавить для него `[L]`. Если же это правило не сработает, т.е. там нет `page`, то будет проверяться следующее правило.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а то я уже все передумал, а все оказывается так просто. Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а если у меня еще есть одно правило такого же типа: RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ inex.php?val=$1&val1=$2&city=$3 , только здесь уже не page a city, тогда как правильно сделать? Поробовал его тоже в самый верх прописать и добавить [L] но этот номер уже не проходит